# How to use a scope variable in view to assign new value in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am a newbie in angularjs and want to use the variable like thing for updating values like we do in php as take a variable and update, Initialize all the stuff.

I have to use a variable and update it on certain condition to make class applicable in the particular condition.

Currently I have set a variable named class in controller with

`$scope.classButton=0;`

In view part I want to update the value of classButton = 1 and under ng-repeat it will have to reinitialize to 0 at starting point.

Comment: Still not sure of what you are trying to achieve. May be include the expected result would help.

Comment: classButton has value 0 and in the view part on certain validation the value classButton puts some special style to view and should then change the value to 1 and in the next ng-repeat the value has to be reinitialize as classButton = 0 and then this has to do all

Answer (score 0):

you can change your value from view like this

```
<div ng-click="classButton = classButton + 1">
```